# Why does my brew installation not work?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, path

I installed brew before, but it does not work now.

When I run `brew`, it gives me the error `-bash: brew: command not found`

So I tried to reinstall using the code

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

But it gives me another one :

> It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
>   should do the following before running this installer again:
>   rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup

If I use the command `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup`, it gives back the first error : `-bash: brew: command not found`

What should I do now?

Answer (score 180):

I had the same problem—installed brew, used it, but now it doens't work, ie, `brew` command not recognized *anymore*.

The context of my brew-not-recognized-anymore problem is a bit more specific: I'm using **iTerm** instead of Terminal, I installed brew in the standard way to the standard place, I used brew to install zsh and **oh-my-zsh**, and at that point the brew command stopped working.

I wasn't able to find the solution to my subset of the brew-not-recognized-anymore problem anywhere, so I'm posting the solution in case anyone else has this sort of brew-not-recognized-anymore problem.

Adding this to my `.zshrc` solved the problem on a machine with Apple M1 CPU:

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Note that this is *not* the same as adding to the PATH variable. The brew command is indeed located in those standard locations listed in other solutions. It turned out not to be a PATH variable thing that was causing this subset of the brew-not-recognized-anymore problem.

Comment: I don't know if it needs to be run every time I load my terminal, but this is the command brew had me run after installation (right after one other command) and that fixed my issue.

Comment: I am using Apple Mac M1 Pro CPU. This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I had exactly the same issue as Matt, brew was not recognized anymore after installing oh-my-zsh. The above solution works, but I have to run that command every time I open the terminal. Is there a way to make it permanent?

Comment: @cholo14 `open -a textedit ~/.zshrc` and add the command on it's own line at the top of the file and save the file. if the file doesn't exist, create it by running `touch ~/.zshrc`

Comment: Can confirm that > eval "$(homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)" is enough to get my brew back up and running. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: For those using `fish` adding the same snippet to `.config/fish/config.fish` makes it work for `fish` on an M1 Mac. Thanks for the solution 

Comment: Keep in mind you may have to re-open your Terminal window for changes to path or changes made by eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"  to be recognised.

Comment: re: "It turned out not to be a PATH variable thing" -- 

Btw, this fixed my problem too, which _was_ a PATH variable thing.

This is because the `brew shellenv` command outputs commands to set PATH and a few other variables.

Answer (score 111):

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

This code works for me on a MacBook Pro M1.

PS: If you are using `bash` on M1, run

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

instead of the first line above.

Comment: can confirm that this is the right way - I type in `brew help shellenv` and it says
`Consider adding
evaluation of this command's output to your dotfiles (e.g. ~/.profile,
~/.bash_profile, or ~/.zprofile) with: eval "$(brew shellenv)"`

Comment: The applications I installed were working only in the terminal window I was installing. When I closed the window I had to re-install it. 

I added these commands to the text opened with the "nano ~/.bash_profile" command and closed it. After this process, everything worked as it should.

Comment: to make it work on M1 with bash, more or less same but: `echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: can confirm on my M2 as well. thank you so much.

Comment: `no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew`

Answer (score 27):

"Command not found" indicates that the `brew` binary isn't on one of the directories listed in your PATH environment variable. To check what your path is currently, run `echo $PATH`. By default, brew installs to `/usr/local/bin`. To set the path permanently, you should edit your `~/.bashrc` file to contain the line `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`.

On Aplle Silicon machines brew by default install path is `/opt/homebrew/bin`

Comment: yes, I already did it.

Comment: did you also rebooted your mac? this is mandatory after changes in bash/bashrc/bash_profile

Comment: @Alessiox no it is not necessary to reboot the mac - only need to start a new Terminal and run from there (or even on most cases resource ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 16):

If your shell is `zsh` and your Mac is M1-based, enter these two commands after installing `brew`:

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

The first command adds:

- an expanded `PATH` variable that includes the directories where `brew` and commands installed with `brew` are located
- several shell variables used by `brew`

to the `.zprofile` initialization file.

The second command adds those same variables to the current shell, so that you can start using `brew` without re-reading `.zprofile`.

PS: For Intel Macs, use `/usr/local` instead of `/opt/homebrew`.

PPS: If you are running `bash`, use `.bashrc` instead of `.zprofile`.

Comment: For most homebrew installs and definitely when this question was written Homebrew install in /usr/local as one of its main selling points so that you don't need to edit the PATH in any shell files. Only in the last few months has it been forced to use a more standard Unix path and you have to edit the PATH

Comment: Also this assumes both an M1 Mac (Homebrew installs to `/opt/homebrew` on M1 only) and use of `zsh` (which is the modern default but doesn't automatically apply to accounts created before the switch). Can you edit the answer to make it more generic, and also explain what the commands actually do and how they solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: It Works!

macOS: Big Sur (version 11.4)
Chip: Apple M1

Answer (score 14):

the `-bash: brew: command not found` error means that it didn't find the `brew` environment variable on your Mac.

The correct environment configuration in `.bash_profile` file should be like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

So if you haven't config the `brew` environment variable, the correct step to config the `brew` environment variable on your Mac is:

1. add the environment variable to your mac, the correct command is:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
2. Now we need to activate the changes. Type this command to activate and try `drew doctor` again:

   ```
   source .bash_profile
   ```

   Or if you had config the environment, you can use this command to open the file to check if the environment configuration is correct:

   ```
   /usr/bin/open ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   and then fix it to the correct text and then save and quit.
3. Don't forget to activate your changes also. Still this command:

   `source .bash_profile`

Comment: Depending on where `brew` was installed you might have to replace `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` with `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin`. All other steps are equal.

Answer (score 5):

If your shell is zsh and your Mac is M1-based

edit .zshrc

```
nano .zshrc
```

add

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Quit terminal and re-open

try with

```
brew
```

Comment: If your Mac is M1 based, you could edit the PATH variable with ```~/.bash_profile```  add ```export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin``` and save. Exit the terminal. Now run  brew command

Comment: tnx, work for me!

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ has a section on this and a specific uninstall script, start there to get a clean system and then install again.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md

> To uninstall Homebrew, paste the command below in a terminal prompt.
>
> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
>
> Download the uninstall script and run ./uninstall --help to view more uninstall options.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that you just never downloaded.. I made that mistake. Thought I'd downloaded right, but found out I hit something other then return when it says to "press return to continue or any other key to cancel"

Comment: No because the OP says he gets the error "It appears Homebrew is already installed. "

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did on Ubuntu 20:

```
echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"'>> ~/.bashrc
```

in contrast with what brew documentation suggests:

> ==> Next steps:
> Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
>
> echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >>
> /home/user/.profile
>
> eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

It seems ***.profile*** does not get read when ***.bashrc*** is there.

Comment: Incorrect. .profile is not read if .bash_profile exists .bashrc is read by all interactive bash sessions see bash documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: @mmmmmm This is also mentioned in ".profile" but ".bash_profile" is not there and yet thet first does not get read. The point is that this solution works.

Comment: Agreed that it works but the reason is wrong - to check on that how are you starting bash

Answer (score -1):

I chased my tail with the "***command not found***" error.  I thought upgrading to *Catalina* might have borked my Homebrew installation (*upgrading OSX requires you to upgrade **MacPorts***).

### Half-Broken:

I checked my path and `/usr/local/bin` was there and an `ls -al` of that directory listed the installed Homebrew packages. So why was Homebrew still not happy?!?!? I tried another Homebrew command and that command **SUCCEEDED**.  So Homebrew was half-broken: some things work, some things don't.  Drat.

### Solution:

The command puking the error ***command not found*** was `mtr` which requires `sudo` access.  Although the Homebrew documentation and every other answer I found on this error tells you to add `/usr/local/bin`to your path, executables requiring `sudo` access live in the path:

```
/usr/local/sbin
```

Add this to:

```
/etc/paths
```

And things will work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

the easy answer here is: you need to read the output of the installation.

after your run the brew command it will guide you what to do next.

In my case it did tell me to run the following 2 commands to make brew available at the PATH

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/moelwekil/.zprofile    
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Answer (score -2):

Following command doesn't work if your are under proxy.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Instead use following -

```
ruby -e "$(curl -x http://DOMAIN%5cUSER_NAME:PASSWORD@PROXY:PORT -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Note we have to use %5c instead of "\" Similarly if your password has any special character replace it with unicode e.g for @ use %40 
Refer this [Unicodes](https://unicode-table.com/en/)

Replace above command with your own params

DOMAIN - Your Domain

USER_NAME - Your User Name

PASSWORD - password

PROXY - 10.10.10.10

PORT - 8080

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/brew /usr/local/bin/brew
```

This line bind **homebrew** from `/opt` with `/usr/local`, so you can use `brew` command everywhere.
This is the only thing that helped me.

[source](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10191#issuecomment-755913250)

Comment: Woudn't it be easier to add `/opt/homebrew/bin` to `PATH` then, with the additional benefit that any command installed via Homebrew will also work?

Comment: @nohillside I don't know, bro. Nothing else worked but this, so I shared the solution. Do you understand?:))