# rsync 3.x on M1 Mac

Tags: mac, homebrew, rsync

Previously, rsync could simply be upgraded on a Mac to 3.x version by homebrew. As command, I used
/usr/local/bin/rsync
instead of just
rsync (which used the preinstalled 2.x version).

On a MacMini M1, rsync 3.x appears no more in this location but I find it under
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rsync/3.2.6/bin/rsync

So how to use rsync 3.x command now? The location seemingly will change if rsync 3.x was alternatively installed e.g. using MacPorts.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph. As for the first you need to alter your PATH to include rsync - I think there is a HomeBrew command to link it into /opt/homebrew/bin

Comment: As far as I understand your comment correctly: you suggest to set the PATH to /opt/homebrew/bin?

Comment: Yes but I think you need another brew coimmand to make a loink in that directory. Putting /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rsync/3.2.6/bin on your PATH would work but then you need to do that for each executable and chnage it when the version or the executable chnages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew sets up softlinks in its bin folder specifically to deal with different installed package versions. eg:

```
~ ls -l $(which rsync)    
lrwxr-xr-x  1 andyg  admin  31 25 Aug 11:49 /opt/homebrew/bin/rsync -> ../Cellar/rsync/3.2.5/bin/rsync
```

Adding just the `/opt/homebrew/bin` to the $PATH means you miss out on the man and info pages too. `brew shellenv` provides the correct path additions. eg.

```
~ brew shellenv
export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew";
export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar";
export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew";
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}";
export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:";
export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
```

You don't use this directly, but a command calling it is added to your shell startup files. So just the correct incantation of the `brew shellenv` command is needed to setup the relevant env vars. This is what's suggested at the end of the brew install script.... (From a very prominent question in the Related column (64 votes) https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430904/221742 )

For an M1 Mac (and assuming zsh):

```
~ echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
~ eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Then (in  my experience) close your Terminal, maybe even logoff / on, even though the second command should setup the $PATH immediately for the current session.

This addition has only been required since brew was available for native Apple Silicon, installing to `/opt/homebrew`. Beforehand the bin was found in the default $PATH. Now it has to be added especially.

By default the Intel installation still goes into `/usr/local`, with binaries into `/usr/local/bin`, already in $PATH by default. Be aware there are security risks associated with this method for Intel.